# How to define an element with empty $value dependent on its use?

Tags: xml, string, testing, xsd, schema

Working in XSD 1.1
I have a schema that includes text elements in which I am supposed to mark certain words with the tag "keyword". Something like this:

*ex 1:*
`<text>I have a <keyword>specific</keyword> taste.</text>`

These keywords can either stand as seen or also be part of a category which is defined as an optional attribute within the keyword element. The keyword either is supposed to refer to such a category, or to have the searched keyword inside as string or to display a combination of both. So they should be freely intermixable like this:

*ex 2:*
`<text>The <keyword group='weapon'>sword</keyword> that I used is <keyword group='smithing'/>made of <keyword>steel</keyword>.</text>`

So far so good. But now I am supposed to build a condition-structure that also uses these keywords but without showing them inside the text itself. So it is asked for only refering to them like in the second example when only the category is referenced but no string is inside the keyword-element. This is mandatory because all strings inside elements are later supposed to be read by another program. The aim is something like this:

*ex 3:*
`<text><condition><keyword group='sword'/><keyword group='handle'/></condition>By now swinging it, the sheer fore is cutting through my <keyword>enemies</keyword>.</text>`

In comparison, something like this is supposed to be forbidden as the strings inside the conditioned-keyword-element would be displayed in the string that is supposed to be readable later:

*ex 4:*
`<text><condition><keyword group='weapon'>sword</keyword><keyword group='handle'/></condition>By now swinging it, the sheer fore is cutting through my <keyword>enemies</keyword>.</text>`

My task now is to forbid such a structure. How do I realise this? In my schema I assume I need to build an assert as part of the condition-element but I am lost on how to do it. I already tried several approaches like this:

*ex 5:*

```
<xs:complexType name="condition" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="keyword" type="keyword" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5"/>        
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="string-length($value) = 0"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

*ex 6:*

```
<xs:complexType name="condition" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="keyword" type="keyword" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5"/>        
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="$value eq ''"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

*ex 7:*

```
<xs:complexType name="condition" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="keyword" type="keyword" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5"/>        
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="::child::string-length() = 0"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

They all are either not catching the case when I have a wrong XML-Code like in example 4 or are even throwing an error-message that the assertion evaluation failed. What am I doing wrong? How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is easy if you know XPath 2:

```
<xs:complexType name="condition" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="keyword" type="keyword" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5"/>        
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="every $keyword in keyword satisfies string-length($keyword) eq 0"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Thank you so much again. Once again you solved my issue.
Where do you get all this information about asserts from? I have already been searching for days now without finding out even the basics about their syntax. I feel like I always need to resort to some magic or am reliant on you guys helping me with it. It's not my first time I am left confused with an assertion.

Comment: @DanielJanz, assertions use XPath 2.0 (at least version 2.0, I would guess the implementors also have an option to use XPath 3 if they support it anyway) expression by definition, so any XPath 2 tutorial should help. I don't know if anyone has written one for the context of XSD 1.1, I would guess that Priscilla Walmsley, if she has a book on XSD 1.1, does an excellent job of explaining it. I just looked on her website, yes, she has http://datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/ with "An entirely new chapter on assertions".

Comment: Even without the book, her examples might help: http://datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter14.html

Comment: I will certainly have a look into it. Would be nice if I could solve such issues on my own as well!
Thank you very much for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can also be done without assertions (or XSD 1.1): the local element declaration for `keyword` within the complex type of `condition` can have a different type from the global definition for `keyword`, and the local definition can have an empty content model.

Comment: I get your idea but can you display it as an example? Written like this I find it a bit abstract and wouldn't know how to program it.
Isn't the problem that I have in the global `keyword` the possibility of empty content?

Comment: No, sorry, this would take me more than the couple of minutes I allow for answering SO questions. Frankly, if you're writing schemas then you need to understand the concepts well enough to turn my answer into code; if you don't, you need to do more reading.